# How do I get the inverse of a function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have some function `y[x_]:=ax+b` (just an example), how do I obtain `x[y_]:=(y-b)/a` in Mathematica? I've tried `InverseFunction`,`Collect` and they don't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Treat it as an equation and use `Solve`.

```
In:=Solve[y-ax-b==0,x]
Out={{x -> (-b + y)/a}}
```

Comment: You said "... and use `Solve`", and then provided a snippet of code that uses `InverseFunction`. I'm pretty sure the latter was meant to be `Solve`.

Comment: @Gareth: Thanks for catching that. I copied the output from Mathematica, but typed the input here by hand and miswrote. `InverseFunction` does not return that result.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to define a function, you could do:

```
x[y_] := x /. Solve[y == a x + b, x][[1]]

x[1]  

-> (1 - b)/a
```

Answer (score 3):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseFunction.html

Specifically the line:

> In Mathematica, inverse functions are
>   represented using InverseFunction[f].

Answer (score 3):

One way is with Solve:

```
In[29]:= Solve[y == a x + b, x]

Out[29]= {{x -> (-b + y)/a}}
```

Comment: Thanks. R.M. had the same answer too, and was faster by a minute. So I accepted that. However, +1 to you too.